# Detect if control was disposed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my application I have a user control that do async operations using thread pool. 
The thread pool method looks like:

```
private void AsyncFunction(object state)
    {
        ... do the calculation
        //refresh the grid data on the UI thread
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                                               {
                          ... update the ui 
                                               }));
    }
```

My problem is that if the user closes the dialog ... the user control gets disposed and I get the exception:

**Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.**

Do you know a way to detect if the dialog was disposed? I don't want to hae a property on control that the dialog set when closed.
Is there another way of solving this?

Thanks,

Radu

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`Control.IsDisposed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx)

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve 100% of the cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460709/detect-if-control-was-disposed/4460737#4460737 below

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Control.IsDisposed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx) property.

```
try
{
    if(!this.IsDisposed) 
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>

                      {
                                // update my control
                      }
          ));
    }
}
catch ( InvalidOperationException )
{
    // Do something meaningful if you need to.
}
```

Comment: I don't know how could I miss that. I explicitly searched for it :)

Comment: You need to check for `IsDisposed` before calling `BeginInvoke`, because it fails if control is disposed.

Comment: Wouldn't that create problems when other thread disposes control after IsDisposed check and before BeginInvoke call?

Comment: @ironic: yes, it will. simpliest reliable solution here is to use `BeginInvoke()` in `try .. catch(InvalidOperationException){}`.

Comment: @max: Is there any typical solution not using exceptions?

Comment: @ironic: you can subscribe to `Disposing` event and cancel or wait for all async operations to complete.

Comment: This doesn't work, the IsDisposed property can become true right after the if() statement, still making BeginInvoke() bomb.  Move the test inside the lambda.

Comment: @Hans .. thats why ironic is suggesting either to handle the InvalidOperationException or subscribing to Disposing event.

Comment: max is suggesting it, not ironic :)

Comment: Not only is there a race condition, in my program, during  shutdown, BeginInvoke sometimes throws an exception (claiming that the window handle has not yet been created) when IsDisposed is still false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a synchronization object like [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) to signal the working thread that the main thread is about to terminate. Then the worker thread can end its execution.