# Problem with adding item to the list from another form

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I would like to click "add button" to add contacts to the list of contacts in ClientApp, but nothing added to box, only to a list named users.

I want to see new usser nickname on the listbox. But when I evokes function AddContact from other form I don't see new usser on the listbox, from this same is good.

In atributes I see this cell, named "dwa".

Someone will help?

AddUsser:

```
  public partial class NewUser: Form
  {
    ...

     public void New()
     {
        ClientApp.users.Add(new accounts(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));
        ClientApp x = new KlientApp();
        x.AddContact(textBox2.Text);
        this.Hide();
    }
  }
```

ClientApp:

```
public partial class ClientApp: Form
{
    ...

    public void AddContact(string nick)
    {
        contacts.BeginUpdate();
        contacts.Items.Add(nick);
        contacts.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK5aI.png)

To Gellio Gao.
I sew ObjectDisposedException in private void Msg when I close program on go:

```
 private void ShowMsg()
{
    bool temp = true;
    while( temp == true)
    {
        if(DateTime.Now.Second % 3  == 0)
        {  
            Msg();
            showed.WaitOne();
            showed.Reset();
            showed.WaitOne(1000);                  
        }
    }
}

  private void Msg()
{
    ClientLog.send_msg= "Wyswietl wiadomosci";
    ClientLog.received.Reset();

    Thread wątek = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsynchronousClient.StartClient));
    wątek.IsBackground = true;
    wątek.Start();

    ClientLog.received.WaitOne();
   
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (ClientLog.send_msg!= "")
        {
        messages.AppendText(ClientLog.send_msg+ Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }));
    showed.Set();
}
```

Comment: 1) You shouldn't put tags in your question title. The tagging help section explicitly states that you should avoid that. 2) I find your question a bit hard to understand in terms of how the code you've provided matches up with your problem description.

Comment: already corrected

Comment: what is `KlientApp` is that the actual window/Form ? if so, I cant see you actually show it. Its seems like you are creating a new reference, adding to it, and letting it fall out of scope

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? What prevents you from doing what you want to?

Comment: John. I wan,t to see new usser nickname on the listbox. But when i evokes function from other form I don't see new usser on the listbox.

Comment: @Maniek Is the variable `messages` a UI control on the current window? It seems that the method `Msg()` still be called in `ShowMsg()` after you closed the window. You should check if the control has been disposed. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460709/detect-if-control-was-disposed).

Comment: Yes, implicitly is a window with massages from ussers. Thx, I'll see.

Comment: @Gellio Gao I use try, catch, and when I close this window, this error does not occur. But aplication doesn't close.

Comment: okej, I have It.
Komun
 try
            {
                if (!this.IsDisposed)
                {
                    Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {...}));
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }But i don't now is it good

Comment: @Maniek I think you should also put the IsDisposed check in the while loop of the method `ShowMsg`, like: `while(!this.IsDisposed){ ... }`. The reason why the application doesn't close is the while loop still running after you close the window.

Comment: Ok, thx. I do that, but I'm currently on a vacation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an instance of `ClientApp` to `NewUser` instead of creating a new instance inside of `NewUser`. Something like:

```
   public partial class NewUser: Form
   {
        private ClientApp _client;
        public NewUser(ClientApp client)
        {
            this._client = client;
        }
    ................
        public void New()
        {
            ClientApp.users.Add(new accounts(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));
            this._client.AddContact(textBox2.Text);
            this.Hide();
        }
   }
```

Update: Give a sample of using `this._client`.

Comment: Ok, but how to run it now? Because I have to give an argument in NewUser() to use it. If I run like this:  NewUser konta = new NewUser(this), this doesn't work

Comment: @Maniek I have updated the answer to show you how to use `this._client`, check it out.

Comment: @Maniek Could show me the code where threw the `ObjectDisposedException`, it seems that you try to use an object that has been disposed. ps: You just need to paste the relevant code onto your question.

Comment: I added this to my question